# Has Annette Obrestad played more hands of poker than Doyle Brunson?

Tags: online, hand, wsop

There have been videos and other public claims about Annette Obrestad having already played more hands of poker than Doyle Brunson. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very much possible. Doyle Brunson played about 1.8 million hands of poker prior to winning his first WSOP bracelet. This article explains how a online player can easily reach this same mark. Annette Obrestad most likely did the same thing. For a dedicated online player, 1.8 million is a very reasonable milestone: http://buriedinfo.com/annette-obrestad-doyle-brunson/

Comment: interesting article, and it's feasible she has, but it's making a mismatched comparison - it is claiming Annette has already played more hands than Doyle has in his career, but then does the math comparing how many hands she has likely played versus Doyle *before he won his first bracelet*.  Since that was 40 years ago, and we don't know (from the article) how much poker Doyle has played during that time, this makes the actual comparison more difficult.

Comment: Is this a direct link to your own site Jim? If so you MUST state it clearly as Ive been informed by the broader Mod community (http://poker.stackexchange.com/help/behavior ... Last section). Otherwise  the post will have to be deleted. Please do that with the rest of your linked posts, Thanks.

Comment: http://poker.stackexchange.com/help/promotion Here are the details.